# Unable to load the requested file error in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am getting this problem.

```
Unable to load the requested file:
http://localhost/grf_new/index.php/reservation/details/34/.php
```

the code looks like this

```
$this->load->view(base_url().index_page().'/reservation/details/'.$userid.'/', $data);
```

Comment: is there any way to remove '.php' which is added automatically.

Comment: Is there a file that in folder views/reservation/details/34.php? You are loading view file not URL

Comment: no... actually reservation is class, details is function and 34 is parameter to that function

Answer (score 3):

**Codeigniter Documentation:** http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

## Loading a View

To load a particular view file you will use the following function:

```
$this->load->view('viewfile', $yourdata);
```

Where viewfile is the name of your view file. Note: The .php file extension does not need to be specified unless you use something other than .php.

Now, open the controller file you made earlier called blog.php, and replace the echo statement with the view loading function:

```
<?php
class Reservation extends CI_Controller {

    function details($id)
    {
        $this->data['user_info'] = $this->user_model->getUser($id)->result();
        $this->load->view('userdetails', $this->data);
    }
}
?>
```

If you visit your site using the URL you did earlier you should see your new view. The URL was similar to this:

```
example.com/reservation/details/34
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't add `base_url()`

Load files using this

```
$this->load->view('test/test', $data);
```

create a file in view folder if your folder like this

```
application/views

test/test.php

//---------------------

//If you want to read the URL use file_get_contents() function
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (doesnt test) :

```
$this->load->view('reservation/details/'.$userid, $data);
```

Comment: here reservation is controller class , so how do you call it in view?